# How to style parent component in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm currently building a custom overlay component using Vue 2.x. There's a prop for the component that allows it to be either have an absolute position or a fixed position.

The issue is that when I turn on the absolute position, I want to add `position: relative` to the parent component. I want this to be a re-usable component, so I want to be able to do this without knowing anything about the parent (id, class, etc.). What is the best approach here to add a style attribute to the custom component's parent?

This is what my custom component currently looks like:

```
<template>
  <component
    class="custom-overlay"
    :style="overlayStyle"
    :is="type"
    v-if="value">
    <slot :style="overlayContentStyle">
    </slot>
  </component>
</template>

<script>
import { colorShiftHelpers } from '../../mixins/helpers'

export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      default: true,
      type: Boolean
    },
    dark: {
      default: false,
      type: Boolean
    },
    absolute: {
      default: false,
      type: Boolean
    },
    color: {
      default: 'rgb(23, 30, 38)',
      type: String
    },
    opacity: {
      default: 0.46,
      type: Number | String
    },
    type: {
      default: 'div',
      type: String
    },
    zIndex: {
      default: 5,
      type: Number | String
    }
  },
  mixins: [colorShiftHelpers],
  computed: {
    overlayStyle({ absolute, color, opacity, zIndex }) {
      return {
        position: absolute ? 'absolute' : 'fixed',
        background: this.addAlpha(color, opacity),
        'z-index': zIndex
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.custom-overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that unless you use the component in dozens of places. Not only is this a code smell, it's also problematic if the parent is positioned in some way other than `relative`.

Comment: Ok - thank you for the suggestion. Can you explain why it's bad practice to do so (i.e. why it's code smell?), and what you would suggest doing instead?

Comment: In general, a codebase is easier to maintain if its sub-units (in this case components) have explicit relationships. Your desired solution is an implicit relationship - the act of adding component C to component P, will alter P. Imagine a year later, you convert P to be a modal and suddenly it breaks because of C's behavior. An explicit solution is just add `position: relative` to P, with a comment, or add a class like `o-container` to P where `o-container` is a reusable CSS object class with an understood purpose in your app.

Comment: Any way you set this up will be messy but another approach could be to pass the parent as a slot into this component and that way you should be able to modify both styles from in here.

PS, you most likely wouldn't want to set it up in vuex in case you have multiple components on the same screen and don't want one to alter all the other parents. (unless this is your goal)

Comment: @David Weldon thank you - that's what I ended up doing, adding a re-usable class to the parent. What you said makes sense. As a self-taught and relatively new coder it's good to learn these rules of coding.

Comment: @MattAft yes that's what I thought. I wouldn't use a vuex store for this either.

Comment: @CathyHa Sounds good. I'd recommend you add an answer and accept it, so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

There is two possible ways to achieve that:

**Whith Vuex**

Control all the styles from a single state variable.

**Store**

```
state: {
  absolute: false;
}
mutations: {
  setAbsolute(state, value) {
    state.absolute = value  // Here value should be true or false
  }
}
```

**Parent**

```
<template>
  <div :class="{relative: absolute}">
    <child-component
      :is-absolute="absolute"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      absolute() {
        return this$store.state.absolute
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

in the previous example i have a variable called absolute on the store and a mutation to set that property with a value, you sould always pass a boolean in this case, you can also make a switcher mutation like this:

```
mutations: {
    switchAbsolute(state) {
      state.absolute = !state.absolute
    }
  }
```

whenever you want to change that just call

```
  $store.commit('switchAbsolute')
```

or the following if you want to set the value manually with the first approach

```
  $store.commit('setAbsolute', [the value you want absolute to be])
```

The value of absolute is receibed as a computed property on your parent and from there you can control the style of the parent and pass the same value as a prop to the child. Pay attention to the conditional class binding, the .relative class should set the position to relative.

**With watchers and events**

The logic is the next: On the child component, you emit an event whenever the prop changes and handle the event on the parent to changet its styles:

**Child**

```
props: {
  absolute: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
},
watch: {
  absolute: function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal === true) {
      this.$emit('childIsAbsolute')
    }
  }
}
```

**On the parent***

```
<template>
  <div :styles="relativePosition">
    <child-component @childIsAbsolute="handleChange($event)" 
     :absolute="absolute"
    />
  </div>
</template>
<scrip>
  export default {
    data() {
      relative: false;
      absolute: false
    },
    methods: {
      handleChange(event) {
        this.relative = event //here event is true or false, depending  
        on the value of the child's prop, emited from the watcher
      }
    },
    computed: {
      relativePosition() {
        return `position: ${this.relative ? 'relative' : 'static'}`
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

What we have done here is:

set a prop absolute for the child and we watch it to emit an event when it changes, the event sends the new value of the prop to the parent and we react to that event and change the styles depending on that new value (true if the child is absolute and false if it's not).
I don't really know where do you handle the value for that prop, in this example i made it's not necessary to handle it with events becaus we actually have the value we want to react to in the parent, but i don't really know where do you send that from.

Comment: It seems kind of excessive to use a vuex store for this...doesn't it?

Comment: The other way around is emiting an event on the child when the prop changes and reacting to that on the parent, i'll add that to the answer

Comment: The prop doesn't change - it's just an option

Comment: then the solution is simpler, just store the option value inside a variable on the parent and pass it to the child, and that way you can react to that variable from the parent and from the child via the prop. It's not really clear what you mean when saying "Without knowing anything from the parent".

Answer (score 0):

As David Weldon has stated in my question's comment, what I'm trying to achieve (making a child component manipulate a parent's style when the child's prop is x) is actually not advised in clean coding practices. He's said it better, so I'll paste his comment here:

> In general, a codebase is easier to maintain if its sub-units (in this
>   case components) have explicit relationships. Your desired solution is
>   an implicit relationship - the act of adding component C to component
>   P, will alter P. Imagine a year later, you convert P to be a modal and
>   suddenly it breaks because of C's behavior. An explicit solution is
>   just add position: relative to P, with a comment, or add a class like
>   o-container to P where o-container is a reusable CSS object class with
>   an understood purpose in your app.

What I ended up doing is just creating a reusable css class and adding that to the parent's class, rather than making the child component manipulate the parent component's style.

```
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
```

I wouldn't suggest using a vuex state for this - as MattAft has noted in the comments as well.